# Group multiple objects into one in a collectionView

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a `collectionView` with some elements inside it, which have a `DateTime` property. The graphic of each element is defined within the `DataTemplate`, but I would like that when there are multiple elements with the exact same `DateTime` property, they would be 'grouped' into a single object in the graphic

NOW:

[image: Now]

Later:

[image: Later]

Comment: use grouping - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/grouping

Comment: in this collectionView I already use groups. Is it possible to create further subgroups?

Comment: @StefanoAPP About collectionview group, it seems to be only provide by jason. Not clear what it means **further subgroups**

Comment: Jason he advised me to create groups inside the collectionView but I already create groups for other always inside that Collectionview, so I could create other different groups yet? Otherwise what could be another way?

Comment: @StefanoAPP Do you try to take a look the link that Jason provided?

Comment: I have elements in my CollectionView. They are grouped within groups. Each group is divided by month. therefore, within each group I have all the elements of the same month, and should I therefore create additional groups to group the elements within that have the exact same date as DateTime?